# Set border edges in HorizontalBarChart

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I need help creating this style BarChart, only the rounded end edges.

I'm using the library "MPAndroidChart" but not have this feature. finally, recomended any library having this feature, rounded end edges and horizontal bar chart with negative, please

I use this line in method "drawDataSet" from "HorizontalBarChartRenderer"

```
c.drawRoundRect(new RectF(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                buffer.buffer[j + 3]), 50,50, mRenderPaint);
```

but this is the result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPwfT.png

and i need set border only left edge : https://i.stack.imgur.com/tehiD.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to draw a smaller normal rectangle in the foreground or background of your "actual" rounded rectangle that will fill up the one side of your rectangle that should not be rounded.

E.g.

```
canvas.drawRect(...);
canvas.drawRoundRect(...);
```